# how to remove the append child element in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<label id="1" >a</label><label id="2" > b </label>
```

I have two labels created. When a label is clicked, I create a `div` element within that I displayed. Now I need to remove the created `div` element if the label is again clicked.

```
if (click == 1) {
    var prevWin = document.createElement("div");
    prevWin.id = 1;
    prevWin.innerHTML = outMsg;
    document.body.appendChild(prevWin);
} else {
    var prevWin = document.body.getElementsById(1);
    document.body.removeChild(prevWin);
}
```

When a label is clicked the `div` element is created successfully. But when it is clicked again, the `div` element is not removed.

Answer (score 3):

```
function labelOnClick () {
    var divs = this.getElementsByTagName("div");

    if (divs.length) {
        divs[0].parentNode.removeChild(divs[0]);
    } else {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = outMsg;

        this.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

`ids` have got to be unique throughout the DOM; in your example, it looks like you'll have the label and the div with the same id. You could easily append a string to the `div` id, if you want it to have an id (`div.id = this.id + "_div"`).

My example wont work if you have more than one div in your label; in which case the ID approach would be best (or use a selector library).

Id's could be approached as follows:

```
function labelOnClick () {
    function makeDivId(id) {
        return id + "_div";
    };

    var div = this.getElementById(makeDivId(this.id));

    if (div) {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    } else {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = outMsg;
        div.id = makeDivId(this.id);

        this.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.....but what to do. if we want to have more than one div element. i the above example.

Comment: You can have multiple `div` elements, but only one per `label`. If you need multiple per `label`, you could apply a `className` to the `divs`, and filter them that way. If you can guarantee that all div descendants of the `label` will need to be removed, then just iterate over the array in the first example, calling `div[i].parentNode.remove(div[i])` on all of them.

Comment: Alternately, you could use unique id's on all the divs; `div_1`, `div_2`, `div_3`, and remove them all manually. Finally, you could put all the `divs` in a single child (another div?) and then iterate over the `childNodes` of the label, and remove that element.